# Упор камеры в границу мира, как осуществить?

Tags: unity3d, камера, элементы-управления

вид игры по типу 2.5D стратегии в изометрии.

Есть одна камера и спрайты *земли

сделал карту из тайлов - в цикле из префабов

[image: вид карты]

сделал управление камерой- по нажатию клавиши изменяется transform.position у камеры

теперь камера двигается, но бесконечно, а хотелось бы **чтобы вьюпорт камеры не уходил за край тайлов**

[image: уход вьюпорта за тайлы]

пробовал сделать прозрачную стену и повесить на стенку и на камеру boxCollider 2D и Rigibody 2D без гравитации на одинаковом значении по Z оси, но свободно проходят через друг друга, пробовал сделать cube и повесить на него и на камеру boxCollider 3D и Rigibody 3D тогда без гравитации, но улетают при столкновении оба, да еще и камеру крутит сильно, почитав доки на rigibody я понял что там можно все это как-то отключить

Но остался вопрос: - **Как сделать чтобы boxCollider 3D на камере был размером с вьюпорт камеры, который меняется в зависимости от разрешения экрана и orthographicSize, который я использую как зум?**

Comment: У тебя есть координаты камеры. Есть координаты и размеры карты. При передвижении камеры проверяй не вышла ли она за границы карты. И не надо никакой физики и стен.

Comment: @ValeraKvip координаты камеры есть, но незнаю как остать координаты вьюпорта т.е. координаты камеры это ее центр, а нужна рамка которая зависит от разрешения и зума

Comment: Да это сложно. Нет ничего плохого что бы камера так выходила, во многих игра так. Или же можно просто сделать  область по которой двигается камера- меньше чем карта  игрок не сможет взаимодействовать с той областью, но в камере она будет.  Пример https://youtu.be/1teeLZoGUTo?t=130   Там за красную линию нельзя зайти и камера не залетит, но карта больше чем область в которой идет игра.

Answer (score 1):

Условия использования: **Viewport Rect** *стандартный и не изменяется*. **orthographicSize** *может меняться*. **Разрешение экрана** *может меняться*.

Получаем **локальные границы камеры** (относительно ее центра)

*объявление переменных:*

```
float horBound;//расстояние до границы по горизонтали
float vertBound;//расстояние до границы по вертикали
```

*вычисление:*

```
vertBound = camera.orthographicSize;
horBound = camera.orthographicSize / Screen.height * Screen.width;
```

Получаем **глобальные границы камеры** (в мировых координатах)

*объявление переменных:*

```
//левая, правая, верхняя, нижняя граница соответственно
float leftBound, rightBound, upBound, downBound;
```

*вычисление глобальных границ:*

```
leftBound = transform.position.x - horBound;
rightBound = transform.position.x + horBound;
upBound = transform.position.y + vertBound;
downBound = transform.position.y - vertBound;
```

Думаю теперь вам не составит труда решить вашу задачу.